# Need help with small Solr problem

Tags: java, php, sql, mysql, database

I have a String field where I store two-word area names.
Ex: `New York`

Thing is, whenever I try to query that field (`area:New York`) no results come up, even though it is stored exactly as New York.

Why is this?

The results DO come up if I search like this: `area:"New York"` but they wont come up if searching like this: `area:New`.

Any ideas?

Here is the field-definition in the schema.xml file:

```
  <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
  <field name="area" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true"/>
```

If you need more input let me know!

Thanks

UPDATE

```
   $fq.=" + area:$state";
```

I am sending this, and Solr receives this as the variable inside state (New York)...

How can I rewrite this so it sends the variable as "New York" (with double quotes)...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a conflict with the reserved keyword `New` have you tried to retrieve similar results using a different two-word area, such as `Las Vegas`?

Also, if the area field is expecting a `String` to always use quotes around your variables.

#### EDIT:

I do not have any experience using SOLR but assuming `area:$state` holds `New York`, I would try inserting the quotes into my code, like so:

```
$fq.=" + area:\"$state\" ";
```

It might not be correct, but it could help point you in the right direction.

Comment: could you tell me how I should send this variable WITH the double-quotes, check my update for details!

Comment: It's now correct, I will post a new Q about the quotes.. thanks

Comment: I wasn't sure where the value of `New York` was being held, could have been `area:$state` or just `$state` itself, but I hope it helped.